# How to convert NSSize, NSinteger and other data types to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsstringencoding

I'm new to Obj C and didn't find any solution to convert given data types to NSString. 
Please help !

Answer (score 1):

```
NSStringFromCGSize, NSStringFromCGRect , NSStringFromCGPoint, etc.

NSInteger x = 5; //x can be float type
NSString *string = [@(x) stringValue];
```